# Go exec.CommandContext is not being terminated after context timeout

Tags: linux, go, process

In golang, I can usually use `context.WithTimeout()` in combination with `exec.CommandContext()` to get a command to automatically be killed (with SIGKILL) after the timeout.

But I'm running into a strange issue that if I wrap the command with `sh -c` *AND* buffer the command's outputs by setting `cmd.Stdout = &bytes.Buffer{}`, the timeout no longer works, and the command runs forever.

Why does this happen?

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "os/exec"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 100*time.Millisecond)
    defer cancel()

    cmdArgs := []string{"sh", "-c", "sleep infinity"}
    bufferOutputs := true

    // Uncommenting *either* of the next two lines will make the issue go away:

    // cmdArgs = []string{"sleep", "infinity"}
    // bufferOutputs = false

    cmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, cmdArgs[0], cmdArgs[1:]...)
    if bufferOutputs {
        cmd.Stdout = &bytes.Buffer{}
    }
    _ = cmd.Run()
}
```

I've tagged this question with Linux because I've only verified that this happens on Ubuntu 20.04 and I'm not sure whether it would reproduce on other platforms.

Comment: I am facing the same issue on my MacOS, when setting cmd.Stdout, the command does not terminate after cancellation of context. I guess there is an issue with `os/exec` package.

Answer (score 5):

My issue was that the child `sleep` process was not being killed when the context timed out. The `sh` parent process was being killed, but the child `sleep` was being left around.

This would normally still allow the `cmd.Wait()` call to succeed, but the problem is that `cmd.Wait()` waits for both the process to exit *and* for outputs to be copied. Because we've assigned `cmd.Stdout`, we have to wait for the read-end of the `sleep` process' stdout pipe to close, but it never closes because the process is still running.

In order to kill child processes, we can instead start the process as its own process group leader by setting the `Setpgid` bit, which will then allow us to kill the process using its *negative* PID to kill the process as well as any subprocesses.

Here is a drop-in replacement for `exec.CommandContext` I came up with that does exactly this:

```golang
type Cmd struct {
    ctx context.Context
    terminated chan struct{}
    *exec.Cmd
}

// NewCommand is like exec.CommandContext but ensures that subprocesses
// are killed when the context times out, not just the top level process.
func NewCommand(ctx context.Context, command string, args ...string) *Cmd {
    return &Cmd{
        ctx:        ctx,
        terminated: make(chan struct{}),
        Cmd:        exec.Command(command, args...),
    }
}

func (c *Cmd) Start() error {
    // Force-enable setpgid bit so that we can kill child processes when the
    // context times out or is canceled.
    if c.Cmd.SysProcAttr == nil {
        c.Cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{}
    }
    c.Cmd.SysProcAttr.Setpgid = true
    err := c.Cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    go func() {
        select {
        case <-c.terminated:
            return
        case <-c.ctx.Done():
        }
        p := c.Cmd.Process
        if p == nil {
            return
        }
        // Kill by negative PID to kill the process group, which includes
        // the top-level process we spawned as well as any subprocesses
        // it spawned.
        _ = syscall.Kill(-p.Pid, syscall.SIGKILL)
    }()
    return nil
}

func (c *Cmd) Run() error {
    if err := c.Start(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return c.Wait()
}

func (c *Cmd) Wait() error {
    defer close(c.terminated)
    return c.Cmd.Wait()
}
```

--- UPDATE ---

Since writing this code I've run into cases where subprocesses sometimes want to join their own process groups, and the setpgid trick no longer works because it will not kill processes in those new process groups. A more robust solution might be to manually traverse the process tree using something like `go-ps`, and for each descendant process, use the following **pseudocode**:

```golang
// KillProcessTree kills an entire process tree using SIGKILL.
func KillProcessTree(pid int) error {
  // Send SIGSTOP to prevent new children from being spawned
  _ = syscall.Signal(pid, syscall.SIGSTOP)
  // TODO: implement ChildProcesses
  for _, c := range ChildProcesses(pid) {
    _ = KillProcessTree(c.Pid)
  }
  // Now that the process is stopped and all descendants
  // are guaranteed to be killed, we can safely SIGKILL
  // this process, without worrying about descendant
  // processes being reparented to pid 1 or anything
  // like that.
  _ = syscall.Signal(pid, syscall.SIGKILL)
  return nil // TODO: better error handling :)
}
```

Comment: So basically you are killing the main head process and because of the code Setpgid = true, all the sub processes are being killed, right ? @Brandon

Comment: @Aliy yep, that is how I understand it